# Nested Lightning Components and Events

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I've built a Lightning App with a Contact Record Home Page built in the App Builder. I'm trying to create a simple Lightning Component to add to the Record Home Page which displays some fields from a related Task. I have my Pane component and an Item component. Ultimately I want to have two Items nested in the Pane, as of now I just have one Item in my code. I've managed to display the fields I want if the Item is added on its own, however adding the Pane to the record home page prevents the page from rendering. I'm by no means a JS expert so the errors on in the console are opaque to me. I don't think I'm doing anything particularly unique so I'm confused what's happening.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Pane -->
<aura:component controller="AccountDevelopmentTaskController" access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
  <aura:registerEvent name="loadTasks" type="c:AccountDevelopmentLoadTasks"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  <c:AccountDevelopmentTaskItem />
```

```
<!-- Item -->
<aura:component controller="AccountDevelopmentTaskController" access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
  <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" access="GLOBAL"/>
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" access="GLOBAL"/>
  <aura:handler name="loadTasks" event="c:AccountDevelopmentLoadTasks" action="{!c.start}"/>
  <div class="row">
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.Subject+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.OwnerId+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.ActivityDate+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.Status}"/>
  </div>
```

```
<!-- Event -->
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/>
```

```
//Pane Controller
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
  var id = component.get("v.recordId");
  var loadTask = component.getEvent("loadTasks");
  loadTask.setParams({"id":id}).fire();
}
```

---

```
//Item controller
start : function(component, event, helper) {
  var id = event.getParam("id");
  var action = component.get("c.loadPlan");
  action.setParams({"tId":id});
  action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var task = response.getReturnValue();
    component.set("v.task", task);
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

---

```
//Apex
@AuraEnabled
public static Task loadPlan(Id tId){
  ... //finding record type id stuff
  return (Task) [SELECT Id, Subject, WhoId, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, Status
                 FROM Task Where (WhoId = :tId) AND (RecordTypeId=:rid) LIMIT 1];
}
```

Here are the console errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  at evalAndReturn
>   (safeEval.html?id=Custom:97)  at safeEval
>   (safeEval.html?id=Custom:122)  at value (safeEval.html?id=Custom:137) 
>   at Object.co (aura_prod.js:839)  at Object.create (aura_prod.js:838) 
>   at Object.qs (aura_prod.js:837)  at eval
>   (AccountDevelopmentTaskPane.js:2)  at nJ.Gc (aura_prod.js:259)  at
>   V.Gc (aura_prod.js:568)  at V.Cb (aura_prod.js:584)
>    Uncaught (in promise) XI {component:
>   "flexipage:runtimeComponent$controller$init", componentStack:
>   "[force:recordLayoutBroker] > [one:recordHomeFlexip…ct__1505850635000]
>        [flexipage:runtimeComponent]", action: null, name: "SyntaxError", message: "Action failed: flexipage:runtimeComponent$controll…e at:
>   components/c/AccountDevelopmentTaskPane.js]", …}

I know there are issues with `null` return cases, for the moment I'm only interested why it doesn't work as such given there is a `Task` of the required record type. If I tweaked the code so the Item was stand alone it worked as desired. So I think there is an issue with how I'm nesting the components and/or the event firing.

I've also tried changing the event type from `COMPONENT` to `APPLICATION` (and the corresponding call in the controller) which hasn't changed the resulting errors.

Comment: Seems like there is some syntax error

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria it does say SyntaxError at evalAndReturn at safeEval. This isn't code I've written. I assume it's some security from SFDC but I'm unsure. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think it's security. Check your code once. The code which you posted seems good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Component events are “clones” of standard DOM events (mouse clicks, key press, and so on). Just like their DOM counterparts, they **propagate up in the component hierarchy** via a bubbling mechanism and can be stopped en route to the application root component.

[image]

It means you can't capture component event in child component so in your case Application Event will work.

[image]

Solution:

> The handler for an application event won’t work if you set the name
>   attribute in `<aura:handler>`. Use the name attribute only when you’re
>   handling component events.

so you need to update your code as

```
<!--Item-->
<aura:component controller="AccountDevelopmentTaskController" access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
  <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" access="GLOBAL"/>
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" access="GLOBAL"/>
  <aura:handler event="c:AccountDevelopmentLoadTasks" action="{!c.start}"/>
  <div class="row">
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.Subject+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.OwnerId+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.ActivityDate+' '}"/>
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.task.Status}"/>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
//Pane Controller
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        var id = component.get("v.recordId");
        var loadTask = $A.get("e.c:AccountDevelopmentLoadTasks");
        loadTask.setParams({"id":id}).fire();
    }
```

Another solution is pass value using `aura:attribute` because firing an event cost most in terms of performance.

```
 <c:AccountDevelopmentTaskItem id="{!parentrecordId}" />
```

Comment: Point out to change the event type to APPLICATION instead of COMPONENT

Comment: @Himanshu both solutions worked. I opted to use the latter and now I'm wondering why I was trying to use events to begin with..

Comment: @JoshD yah second one is better solution